# Jquery Align DIV to Link

Tags: jquery, html, alignment

I'm trying to show a hidden DIV, but I want it to appear next to the link that calls it, not further down the page.

There may be several hyperlinks or image links on the page and I want to allign the 'popup' div to appear next to the link or image that has been clicked.

How do I do this. ?

This is the jquery I'm using :

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
        $("[id$='contact']").click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $("#messagepop").css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

I've created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bm0sascz/)** showing what I have so far.

Thanks

Comment: You have the right code, but you used the wrong selector. You used `#messagepop` when you need `.messagepop`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bm0sascz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is you are referring to the `messagepop` by id (`#messagepop`) not class (`.messagepop`).

Secondly, you can make it appear next to the link, by using [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get the link's position:

```
$(".messagepop").css( {position:"absolute",
                       top:$(this).offset().top,
                       left: $(this).offset().left});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm0sascz/2/)

Comment: Thanks that works great.. anyway to add a close icon to the top right corner ?

Comment: yep you can `position:absolute` a link in the top right. just remember to hook it up to the same `$('.close').click` handler - http://jsfiddle.net/bm0sascz/5/

Comment: - Thanks one last question. is there anyway to stop the popup closing if the same link is clicked again ? or if a new link is clicked ? So you have to close the current one first ?