# Force window closed at correct hyperlink

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, window

Following on from [jQuery Align DIV to Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254002/jquery-align-div-to-link).

I've now got a working script that opens a window next to the link I click.

The issue I have is what happens when another link is clicked when the window is open.  If I click on Link D the window opens.  If I then click on Link A whilst the window is open at 'D' the window closes at Link A.

This **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bm0sascz/6/)** shows what I mean.

What I'd like to do is either. Close the open window and reopen at the new link, or only allow closing via the close link only.

This is the code I'm using:

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });    
}

$(function() {
        $("[id$='contact']").click(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));               
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $(".messagepop").css( {position:"absolute",
                             top:$(this).offset().top,
                             left: $(this).offset().left});
      $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

Any idea who I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem which i could find here, you are using toggle function in animate and trying to control click event. You need to handle animate for show/hide instead of using toggle.

However below JS code is working as expected. please give try if it solves your purpose else try to remove toggle from animation .

```
$(function() {
  $("[id$='contact']").click(function(){
    var src = $(this);
    $("[id$='contact']").removeClass('selected');
    $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
       $(".messagepop").css( {position:"absolute",
                             top:src.offset().top,
                             left:src.offset().left});
       src.addClass('selected');
     }); 

    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($('#contact'));
    return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```